# Python/JSON TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Tags: python, json

After fighting for hours, I need your help.
On a JSON response, I'd like to get ONE result from it.
Here how look the JSON file:
[image]

I want the result to be "Desnoss" only and only once.

```
    data = json.loads(response)
    print("%s" % (data["0"]["team"]["0"]["name"]))
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c1.py", line 48, in <module>
    print("%s" % (data["0"]["team"]["0"]["name"]))
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: Try using integer 0 not string "0".

Comment: why you put the zero in quotes? it's not a key you don't need to put quotes around indexes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pls. try following. 0 is the index and not "0"

```
print("%s" % (data[0]["team"][0]["name"]))
```